# de-compiling python exe to original python source code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a python application that has be converted to windows executable file. 
please can anyone show me how to reverse the process and get the original python source code.
I have tried using PY2EXEDUMPER and Easy Python Decompile but its does not work

Comment: "Does not work" is the most useless description of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard for converting Python code to a Windows executable, and the intention is often to protect the original Python code from actually being readable and understandable.

So don't expect to be able to get any readable Python code out of such a reverse engineering attempt.